# How add values(integer) of checkboxs While Selecting checkboxes and display them simultaneously using JQuery...

Tags: jquery

I want Add values of all CheckBoxes at the time of selecting them and display them as an alert.I new with JQuery.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post some code you have tried..

Comment: Please explain further with details

Comment: <label>Select</label> 
        <div> 
            <label > <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="language" id="One"> One </label> 
            <label > <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="language" id="Two"> Two </label> 
            <label > <input type="checkbox"  value="3" name="language" id="Three"> Three </label></div>      These are three checkboxes when i select two of them it should show me addition of the values of check boxes.

Comment: I have added an button.. when that button is clicked it gives me right ans.. But i want addition at the time of selecting checkboxes. JQuery code for Button Click  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        
     
        $('input[name="language"]:checked').each(function() {
         var selectedLanguage = new Array();
        selectedLanguage.push(this.value);
        });
        var total=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedLanguage.length; i++) {
        total += selectedLanguage[i] << 0;
         }
        alert("Addition of No:-----"+total);
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<input type="checkbox" class="c" value=""/>
<input type="checkbox" class="c" value=""/>

<script>
$(function(){
$(".c").change({
   $(this).attr("value","your value");
 })
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
$(":checkbox").on("change",function(){
  var total = 0;
  $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    total += +$(this).val();
  });
  alert(total);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QxTCL/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

The code is pasted on jsfiddle here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8gfE/)

html:

```
<label>Select</label> 
<div> 
    <label> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="language" id="One"> One </label> 
    <label > <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="language" id="Two"> Two </label> 
        <label > <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="language" id="Three"> Three </label>
```

jQuery:

```
var sumA = 0;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    sumA = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i, elem){
       sumA = sumA + parseInt($(elem).val());
    });

    alert(sumA);

});
```